# Underflow error in floating point arithmetic in C

Tags: c, floating-point, underflow

I am new to C, and my task is to create a function

f(x) = sqrt[(x^2)+1]-1

that can handle very large numbers and very small numbers. I am submitting my script on an online interface that checks my answers.

For very large numbers I simplify the expression to:

f(x) = x-1

By just using the highest power. This was the correct answer.

The same logic does not work for smaller numbers. For small numbers (on the order of 1e-7), they are very quickly truncated to zero, even before they are squared. I suspect that this has to do with floating point precision in C. In my textbook, it says that the float type has smallest possible value of 1.17549e-38, with 6 digit precision. So although 1e-7 is much larger than 1.17e-38, it has a higher precision, and is therefore rounded to zero. This is my guess, correct me if I'm wrong.

As a solution, I am thinking that I should convert x to a long double when x < 1e-6. However when I do this, I still get the same error. Any ideas? Let me know if I can clarify. Code below:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double feval(double x) {
    /* Insert your code here */
    if (x > 1e299) 
    {;
        return x-1;
    }
    if (x < 1e-6)
    {
        long double g;
        g = x;
        printf("x = %Lf\n", g);
        long double a;
        a = pow(x,2);
        printf("x squared = %Lf\n", a);
        return sqrt(g*g+1.)- 1.;
    }
    else
    { 
        printf("x = %f\n", x);
        printf("Used third \n");
        return sqrt(pow(x,2)+1.)-1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    double x;
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    double b;
    b = feval(x);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `pow` returns a `double`.  Converting it to a `long double` after the fact won't change that.  If the result doesn't fit in a `double`, it will overflow.  If you want a `long double` result, then you need to use `powl` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For small inputs, you're getting truncation error when you do 1+x^2. If `x=1e-7f`, `x*x` will happily fit into a 32 bit floating point number (with a little bit of error due to the fact that `1e-7` does not have an exact floating point representation, but `x*x` will be so much smaller than 1 that floating point precision will not be sufficient to represent `1+x*x`.

It would be more appropriate to do a Taylor expansion of sqrt(1+x^2), which to lowest order would be

sqrt(1+x^2) = 1 + 0.5*x^2 + O(x^4)

Then, you could write your result as

sqrt(1+x^2)-1 = 0.5*x^2 + O(x^4),

avoiding the scenario where you add a very small number to 1.

As a side note, you should not use `pow` for integer powers. For x^2, you should just do `x*x`. Arbitrary integer powers are a little trickier to do efficiently; the GNU scientific library for example has a function for efficiently computing arbitrary integer powers.

Comment: **Edit: I understand, I had it backwards. It's for a point x close to a, not point a close to x. 

My understanding is that a taylor series approximation is of the form f(x) ~ f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + ... (at some point a that is close to x). So if we take a to be 1e-7, we still need to compute f(a), which would give us the same problem no? Even taking what you have here, you have 1 + 0.5x^2, where x^2 is going to be a very small number. So how does that avoid the scenario where we are adding 1 to a very small number?

Comment: Re “As a side note, you should not use `pow` for integer powers”: That may be reasonable advice for **small** integer powers, but, for larger integer powers, `pow` may be more accurate than compounded multiplications. Even for modestly sized integers, a faithfully rounded `pow` may be more accurate than multiplications.

Comment: @lcleary We avoid adding a small number to 1 by subtracting off the 1 in our algebra, so that the final result is just 0.5x^2. You would just return `0.5*x*x` from your function for small `x`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever trick. Although the problem seems to be that x is truncated to zero even before it goes into the calculation. If I input 1e-7 into the scanf, then it shows up as 0.0000 when I print it. Is there an issue with my scanf?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here when implementing this in the naive way: Overflow or underflow in intermediate computation when computing `x * x`, and substractive cancellation during final subtraction of 1. The second issue is an accuracy issue.

ISO C has a standard math function `hypot (x, y)` that performs the computation `sqrt (x * x + y * y)` accurately while avoiding underflow and overflow in intermediate computation. A common approach to fix issues with subtractive cancellation is to transform the computation algebraically such that it is transformed into multiplications and / or divisions.

Combining these two fixes leads to the following implementation for `float` argument. It has an error of less than 3 [ulps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) across all possible inputs according to my testing.

```c
/* Compute sqrt(x*x+1)-1 accurately and without spurious overflow or underflow */
float func (float x)
{
    return (x / (1.0f + hypotf (x, 1.0f))) * x;
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that x is truncated to zero even before it goes into the calculation. If I input 1e-7 into the scanf, then it shows up as 0.0000 when I print it. Is there an issue with my scanf?

Comment: @lcleary If you print 1e-7 (0.0000001) as a plain old decimal number with only four decimal places, it would print as zero. Experiment with different `printf()` format specifiers to gain some fluency. Here is a complete program to get started: `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main (void) { float x; scanf ("%f", &x); printf ("x=%23.16e\n", x); return EXIT_SUCCESS; }`. 1e-7 is not exactly resprentable as a `float`, so this program prints something like `x=1.0000000116860974e-007`.

Answer (score 1):

A trick that is often useful in these cases is based on  the identity

```
(a+1)*(a-1) = a*a-1
```

In this case

```
sqrt(x*x+1)-1 = (sqrt(x*x+1)-1)*(sqrt(x*x+1)+1) 
                 /(sqrt(x*x+1)+1)
= (x*x+1-1) / (sqrt(x*x+1)+1)
= x*x/(sqrt(x*x+1)+1)
```

The last formula can be used as an implementation. For vwry small x sqrt(x*x+1)+1 will be close to 2 (for small enough x it will be 2) but we don;t loose precision in evaluating it.

Comment: The problem seems to be that x is truncated to zero even before it goes into the calculation. If I input 1e-7 into the scanf, then it shows up as 0.0000 when I print it. Is there an issue with my scanf?

Comment: @lcleary how are you printing? If you only print 5 decimal places then 0.0 is the right thing to be printed. Try printing it with %e

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with running into the minimum value, but with the precision.

As you said yourself, `float` on your machine has about 7 digits of precision.  So let's take x = 1e-7, so that x^2 = 1e-14.  That's still well within the range of `float`, no problems there.  But now add 1.  The exact answer would be `1.00000000000001`.  But if we only have 7 digits of precision, this gets rounded to `1.0000000`, i.e. exactly 1.  So you end up computing `sqrt(1.0)-1` which is exactly 0.

One approach would be to use the linear approximation of `sqrt` around `x=1` that `sqrt(x) ~ 1+0.5*(x-1)`.  That would lead to the approximation `f(x) ~ 0.5*x^2`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that x is truncated to zero even before it goes into the calculation. If I input 1e-7 into the scanf, then it shows up as 0.0000 when I print it. Is there an issue with my scanf?

Comment: @lcleary: You've got the correct value but you're not printing enough decimal places when you print it. `printf("%f")` defaults to 6 digits.  Try `printf("%.10f")`.